# Get new location for modified hunk

Tags: git, merge-conflict-resolution

Sometimes I see merge conflicts like this:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
...lots of code
line changed by me
...lots of code
line changed by me
...lots of code
=======
>>>>>>> origin/master
```

If I manually look around, I can find the new location but I don't know if the code was moved or both changed and moved (a real conflict). I can only repeat upstream move to see if I made any changes on top of it other than original ones.

Assuming that code is location independent, how can I resolve this situation more easily?

Clarification, this tends to happen if the new location is in a different file.

Comment: Do you use a difftool?

Comment: Yes, `vimdiff`.

Comment: And it doesn't help with situation?

Comment: Actually, it might be a wrong choice in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Git's merge operation, at the point where you see the conflict, is working file-by-file.  If some code that was in file `orig-file.ext` is now in file `new-file.ext`, `git merge` is not going to help you out here.<sup>1</sup>

One thing you *can* do is use `git blame`, aka `git annotate`, to look at commits that have occurred on *their* branch to see where the code has moved.  You will want to consult [the `git blame` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-blame) quite a lot here.  By default, though, to find the new code easily, you need to know the *name of the new file*.  Git will then help you out to find the name of the original file.  But you already know the name of the original file: you want the name of the new file.  Fortunately, there is a `git blame` option that can help here—at least potentially.  Nothing here is guaranteed.

The other thing you can do is use `git grep`.  This may actually be your best bet.  If you are sure that some line(s) are *not* going to be changed in the new code, [`git grep`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-grep) will let you search the tip commit of the other branch for the code.  That will immediately tell you the file name of the new file.

---

<sup>1</sup>If the *whole file* gets renamed, Git *will* help you out here, because it will match up the change-to-the-file in *your* branch with the rename-of-the-file in *their* branch.  You will get a *modify/rename conflict*.  But that is not what happened here.

---

#### Things to remember about the merge

I made an example merge with the same problem, by making conflicting changes to two branches I made off of `master` in a clone of the Git repository for Git:

```
$ git checkout -b move-code master
(move some code, add, commit)
$ git checkout -b change-code master
(modify the same lines I moved; add and commit)
$ git merge move-code
Auto-merging wt-status.c
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in wt-status.c
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

Remember that `git merge` works by comparing some *merge base* commit to the two *branch tip* commits, to see what you changed, and to see what they changed.  (Remember in turn that each commit saves a *full snapshot* of *all* files.)

In my case, I only made two commits, one on `change-code` and one on `move-code`.  But in general, you'll have something like this:

```
          o--o--...--I   <-- move-code (HEAD)
         /
...--o--H
         \
          o--o--...--J
```

This means that commit `H` is the *best* shared commit, between all the commits reachable from `i`, the tip commit of my `move-code`, and `J`, the tip commit of my `change-cde`.  The best shared commit is the merge base.  You can get Git to print out the hash ID of this merge base commit using `git merge-base`:

```
$ git merge-base --all move-code change-code
566a1439f6f56c2171b8853ddbca0ad3f5098770
```

The hash ID that Git prints here is the hash ID of the merge base.<sup>2</sup>

Now, having found the merge base (with `git merge-base` or by eyeballing the graph printed by `git log --graph` or whatever it is that you might use to find it), you *can* see what it is that *Git* sees as what needs to be merged, by running two `git diff` commands:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-H> <hash-of-I>
```

and:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-H> <hash-of-J>
```

or:

```
$ H=$(git merge-base --all change-code move-code); echo $H
566a1439f6f56c2171b8853ddbca0ad3f5098770
$ git diff --find-renames $H change-code
diff --git a/wt-status.c b/wt-status.c
index cc6f94504d..f2bf294275 100644
--- a/wt-status.c
+++ b/wt-status.c
@@ -117,6 +117,7 @@ static void status_printf_more(struct wt_status *s, const char *color,
 {
        va_list ap;

+       // this is status_printf_more
        va_start(ap, fmt);
        status_vprintf(s, 0, color, fmt, ap, NULL);
        va_end(ap);
```

and then:

```
$ git diff --find-renames $H move-code
[much bigger diff, snipped.  This shows both files I changed:
 I moved function status_printf_more to wt-status.h.]
```

The first one shows *what you changed*, and the second shows *what they changed*, or in this case, what I moved.  These are the changes that Git is combining, one pair of files at a time.

Unfortunately for your case, what this shows is: you *changed* the code, and they *deleted* the code, from one file—in my case, from `wt-status.c`.  You believe that they did not merely *delete* the code, they instead *moved* the code from file `orig-file.ext` to `new-file.ext`, just as I moved some code.  You'd have to look through the entire diff output here, to find the file into which they *moved* the code.

---

<sup>2</sup>If this prints more than one merge base, you've likely performed a *recursive merge* and things get more difficult.  There's no one right way to proceed, though you can use each merge base here, if you like.  Note that if you use the `git grep` method you don't need any of this stuff!

---

#### Using `git grep`

Let's say that no matter what happens to the code—no matter where it moves, from `wt-status.c` to _______, it will definitely have the word `status_printf_more` in it.  Then:

```
$ grep -e status_printf_more move-code
```

will show all *files* in the *tip commit* of their branch—in this case, in commit `J`—that have a matching line.  (The `-e` option is not strictly necessary, I just used it here.)  Here's what happens in my case:

```
move-code:wt-status.c:  status_printf_more(s, c, "%s%.*s%s\n", how, len, padding, one);
move-code:wt-status.c:          status_printf_more(s, c, "%s%.*s%s -> %s",
move-code:wt-status.c:          status_printf_more(s, c, "%s%.*s%s",
move-code:wt-status.c:          status_printf_more(s, color(WT_STATUS_HEADER, s), "%s", extra.buf);
move-code:wt-status.c:  status_printf_more(s, GIT_COLOR_NORMAL, "\n");
move-code:wt-status.c:          status_printf_more(s, color(WT_STATUS_UNTRACKED, s),
move-code:wt-status.c:          status_printf_more(s, branch_status_color, "%s", on_what);
move-code:wt-status.c:          status_printf_more(s, branch_color, "%s\n", branch_name);
move-code:wt-status.h:static void status_printf_more(struct wt_status *s, const char *color,
```

Right there, we have our answer: the function is now in `wt-status.h`.

#### Using `git blame`

`git blame` normally works in the wrong direction: from the *last* commit (or some commit you specify) backwards, which is Git's natural direction.  However, it has a `--reverse` option.  It also has an option—`-C`—to find *code moved or copied across a file* at one particular commit.<sup>3</sup>

In my case, the file that I changed the code in, from which I believe `move-code` moved the code, is `wt-status.c`.  So I can use:

```
git blame -C --reverse ${H}^..move-code wt-status.c
```

If I do that, I can find (some of) the moved lines and the name `wt-status.h`, which is where I actually did move them.  But there is a *lot* of output.  I can cut it down using line numbers and the `-s` option:

```
$ git blame -C -s -L 112,139 --reverse ${H}^..move-code wt-status.c
```

git blame -C -s -L 112,139 --reverse ${H}^..move-code wt-status.c

```
d16f83787f3 wt-status.c 112)    va_end(ap);
d16f83787f3 wt-status.c 113) }
d16f83787f3 wt-status.c 114) 
d16f83787f3 wt-status.h 115) static void status_printf_more(struct wt_status *s, const char *color,
d16f83787f3 wt-status.h 116)                           const char *fmt, ...)
d16f83787f3 wt-status.c 117) {
d16f83787f3 wt-status.c 118)    va_list ap;
d16f83787f3 wt-status.c 119) 
d16f83787f3 wt-status.c 120)    va_start(ap, fmt);
[more stuff, snipped]
```

Note that only two lines seem to have "come from" `wt-status.h`, but in this case, that is sufficient.

Note that the range of commits starts one commit *before* commit `$H` (the merge base we found earlier).  That's not always necessary, but it is in this case since the commit in which I moved the code is the commit that is right after `$H`, so I need Git to look at commit `$H` itself as well.